# Pig it method that I am trying to make trouble checking punctuation at the end java

Tags: java, string

I am trying to answer this question.

> Move the first letter of each word to the end of it, then add "ay" to the end of the word. Leave punctuation marks untouched.

This is what I did so far:

```
public static String pigIt(String str) {
    //Populating the String argument into the String Array after splitting them by spaces
    String[] strArray = str.split(" ");
    System.out.println("\nPrinting strArray: " + Arrays.toString(strArray));
    String toReturn = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < strArray.length; i++) {
        String word = strArray[i];
        for (int j = 1; j < word.length(); j++) {
            toReturn += Character.toString(word.charAt(j));
        }

        //Outside of inner for loop

        if (!(word.contains("',.!?:;")) && (i != strArray.length - 1)) {
            toReturn += Character.toString(word.charAt(0)) + "ay" + " ";
        } else if (word.contains("',.!?:;")) {
            toReturn += Character.toString(word.charAt(0)) + "ay" + " " + strArray[strArray.length - 1];
        }
    }
    return toReturn;
}
```

It is supposed to return the punctuation mark without adding "ay" + "". I think I am overthinking but please help. Please see the below debugger.

[image: Testing pigit method]

Comment: Based on the limited information you provided, the output should be "elloHay, orldWay, !" (The quote marks aren't part of the answer.)

Comment: Hint: carefully read the documentation. `word.contains("',.!?:;")` tests if `word` contains the substring `',.!?:;`. This is probably not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

One of the problems here is that your else if statement is never being invoked. The .contains method will not work with multiple characters like that unless you are trying to match them all. In your conditions you are essentially asking if the word matches that entire string "',.!?:;". If you just keep the exclamation point in there it will work invoke it. I don't know how else you can use contains besides making a condition for each one like word.contains("!")|| word.contains(",")|| word.contains("'"), etc.. You can also use regex for this problem.

Alternatively, you can use something like,

```
    Character ch = new Character(yourString.charAt(i));
    if(!Character.isAlphabetic(yourString.charAt(i))) {
```

to determine if a character is not an alphabetical one, and is a symbol or punctuation.

Comment: Note that the `Character` constructor is **deprecated** in newer Java versions. You should always use [`Character::valueOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html#valueOf(char)) instead. This leverages the `Character` cache.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is not relay on `str.split("\\s++")`, because you could have punctuation in any plase. The best one is to look through the string and find all not *letter or digit* symbols. After that you can define a word borders and translate it.

```
public static String pigIt(String str) {
    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0, j = 0; j <= str.length(); j++) {
        char ch = j < str.length() ? str.charAt(j) : '\0';

        if (Character.isLetterOrDigit(ch))
            continue;

        if (i < j) {
            buf.append(str.substring(i + 1, j));
            buf.append(str.charAt(i));
            buf.append("ay");
        }

        if (ch != '\0')
            buf.append(ch);

        i = j + 1;
    }

    return buf.toString();
}
```

**Output:**

```
System.out.println(pigIt(",Hello, !World"));    // ,elloHay, !orldWay
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex may be difficult to start with but is very powerful:

```
public static String pigIt(String str) {
    return str.replaceAll("([a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z]*)", "$2$1ay"); 
}
```

The () specify groups. So I have one group with the first alphabet character and a second group with the remaining alphabet characters.
In the replace parameter you can refer to these groups ($1, $2).
String.replaceAll will search all matching string parts and apply the replacement. Non matching characters like the punctuations are left untouched.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello, World, ! -->"+ pigIt("Hello, World, !"));
    System.out.println("Hello?, Wo$, F, ! -->"+ pigIt("Hello?, Wo$, F, !"));
}
```

The output of this method is:

```
Hello, World, ! -->elloHay, orldWay, !
Hello?, Wo$, F, ! -->elloHay?, oWay$, Fay, !
```